# How to make QTabWidget clickable?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qtabwidget

i searched about this topic and find some examples how to make qwidget clickable but just to print texts like this one 
import sys

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "clicked"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

what i need is it possible to make th QTabWidget clickable and when click on it we can use it like a button to open a file for example ?

Comment: i find a solution but i need more tests to get what i want :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is create a signal and output it as shown below:

```
class ClickableQTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.cw = ClickableQTabWidget(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.cw)
        self.cw.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        print("clicked")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = Widget()
widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: @seghier If it works for you please mark it as correct.

Comment: yes it work as the solution i found with two simple lines : self.tabWidget.mousePressEvent = self.tabOpen1 and def tabOpen1(self, event): self.folder_open.toggle() ; with this way when i click on the tabwidget the button toggled and open/colse the list window

Comment: It is a solution, in particular it works if you are only going to have a widget of that type, in my case I proposed the class since it has a signal that you can connect to multiple slots. If my answer helped you, do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: @seghier In addition, in SO it is customary to give an upvote or mark a response as correct if the answer is correct. and I see you do not, this discourages me to continue helping you.

Comment: don't understand it like that because i didn't try yet tour method ; i need to create new file first and try ; and this is a promise

Comment: @seghier Please take the time to try it as I have taken mine to help you. :P

Comment: @seghier I've updated my answer so you can easily try it out :D

Comment: tonight and you will find my answer here :) ; thanks